# exterior covariant derivative of $\operatorname{End}(E)$-valued $p$-form

Tags: differential-geometry

How can I calculate exterior covariant derivate of $\,\operatorname{End}(E)$-valued $p$-form; i.e.,  $\,d_D(\eta)\;$?

Comment: What is $E$?  What is your diff. geoemtry setting? Where do your specific problems lie?

Comment: E is bundle for example tangent bundle, cotangent bundle. End(E) is endomorphism bundle

Comment: All you need is to consider the definition of covariant derivative for the vector bundle End(E)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Avitus has commented, the derivative of forms is the one induced by that of sections (cf. e.g. Wells p. 74). Let $D$ be a connection in $E$. If $s$ is a section of $E$ and $\Phi$ a section of $\mathrm{End}\, E$, then you can define an induced connection $D^{\mathrm{End}}$ in $\mathrm{End}\,E$ by
$$(D^{\mathrm{End}}_X\Phi)(s) = D_X (\Phi(s)) - \Phi(D_X s)$$
for vector fields $X$ on the base. This comes about by viewing $\mathrm{End}\,E$ as the tensor product bundle $E \otimes E^*$. The connection in $E$ induces one in $E^*$ causing the sign in the above formula (see Wells p. 93), and there is a canonical way (see [this site](http://diffgeom.subwiki.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_connections)) to define a connection in a tensor product bundle, given connections in the factors.